# Using React Hooks to filter the posts by date before mapping through the posts - How to?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React Hooks and have a dummy content array of comments which I am mapping through to display it. Now, I am directly mapping through that array, but I would like `filter => map` before returning the output.

**The hook from main file:**

```
  const [articleComments, setArticleComments] = useState([
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      publishedAt: "22.03.2022",
      image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
      post: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      publishedAt: "03.01.2022",
      image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/301",
      post: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    },
    {
      name: "Jack Doe",
      publishedAt: "17.03.2022",
      image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/302",
      post: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    },
  ]);
```

**Comments.tsx:**

```
 const Comments = () => (
      <div className="w-full px-4 pb-16 pr-4 mx-auto mt-5 md:pt-2 md:max-w-4xl">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 leading-relaxed text-md text-navyBlue">
          {articleComments.length > 0 &&
            articleComments.map(({ image, name, publishedAt, post }: any) => (
              <div key={name} className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
                <div className="col-span-2 md:col-span-1 avatar">
                  <div className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full ring ring-[#65c3c8] ring-offset-2">
                    <img src={image} alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="relative md:-mt-2 col-span-full md:col-span-11">
                  <h4 className="font-bold">{name}</h4>
                  <time>{publishedAt}</time>
                  <p className="mt-2">{post}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    
    export default Comments;
```

Comment: Is this the way they give you the date from the api??? Not very helpful if it is

Comment: Did I say it's an API? I am working on dummy content like mentioned. publishedAt date should be sorted before mapping.

Comment: Yes I know that but the date format is not a good format to receive it in. You cannot do new Date("22.03.2022") because it is invalid so thats why I am saying its a bad way to receive a date format. I can give you an answer if your date is "22-03-2022"

Comment: Good answer thank you. What would be the suggestion to change even if it's dummy data?

Comment: Something like "2022-03-22T03:24:00". I know you are using dummy data but this is how most API's will give a date to you so you can format easily. Better to use the correct format ready for when you integrate with an api. Will post a full answer now.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, nevermind it's not important now anyways. I will make it dynamic later once it's okay for now.